# Computing indegree and outdegree of a digraph

Tags: java, digraphs

first and foremost, I'm on a mobile device so this might not look pretty as the typical editing options are not available. I'm a bit confused on how to carry out finding the indegree and outdegree. This is supplied from Coursera. I'm aware that in degree are edges coming in and out degree are edges going out

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

 class UnweightedGraph<V>
    {
//A HashMap of lists for Adjacency list representation. Key is a   source vertex and 
//value is a list of outgoing edges (i.e., destination vertices) for the key
private HashMap<V,LinkedList<V>> adj;

public UnweightedGraph()
{
    adj = new HashMap<V,LinkedList<V>>();
}

/**
 * A function to add an edge
 * @param source : The source of the edge
 * @param dest: The destination of the edge
 */

public void addEdge(V source, V dest)
{
    LinkedList<V> edgeList = adj.get(source);
    if (edgeList==null)
        edgeList = new LinkedList<V>();

    edgeList.add(dest);
    adj.put(source, edgeList);
}







 /**
 * Computes the in-degree and outDegree for each vertex in the graph
 * @returns a dictionary which maps every vertex to its Degree object containing the in-degree and out-degreeo of the vertex
 */
  public Map<V, Degree> findInOutDegrees()
   {
// TO DO : YOUR IMPLEMENTATION GOES HERE
//Map <V, Degree > computeInOutDegree = new HashMap<V,    Degree>();
adj.
for (V vertice : adj.get(V)) {
    vertice.
}


 }



  }
```

I'm posting this from a mobile device and don't see the typical format code tags. Here is the Degree class:

```
   public class Degree {


//Number off incoming edges to a vertex
int indegree;

//number of outgoing edges from a vertex
int outdegree;

//Constructor
public Degree ( int indegree, int outdegree){

    this.indegree= indegree;
    this.outdegree= outdegree;
}


//Getter and Setter MNethods

public int getIndegree() {
    return indegree;
}

public void setIndegree(int indegree) {
    this.indegree = indegree;
}

public int getOutdegree() {
    return outdegree;
}

public void setOutdegree(int outdegree) {
    this.outdegree = outdegree;
}


   }
```

My question is what exactly am I doing wrong so far in the method to compute inoutdegrees. It's really boggling my mind.

Comment: You forgot to add a question.